# Need help to transfer data from one table to another table in the same database

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, visual-studio-2008

I'm using visual studio 2008 express running C#. I got Cart table and Checkout table in the same database which is an access file. both table have 3 same column which is ProductID,MemberID and Quantity.

So when I click a button in the Shopping cart page, the data in Cart table are supposed to transfer to Checkout table and the data in Cart are supposed to be cleared (which I haven't try yet because the transfer part is not successful). In the configure data source, SQL statement Insert part I wrote:

```
INSERT INTO [Checkout] 
([ProductID], [MemberID], [Quantity]) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
SELECT([ProductID], [MemberID], [Quantity]) 
FROM [Cart] 
WHERE ([MemberID]=?)
```

and the error is (Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement.) come out at the aspx.cs (adsCart.Insert(); ) when I run it. When I try to execute query in configure datasource , the error is (Unable to parse query text.)

(I have also tried another way where the code is

```
string MemberID = User.Identity.Name;
string Product = ??? ;
string Quantity =??? ;   (Both ??? is the part where I do not know what to put in.)   



    adsCart1.SelectParameters["MemberID"].DefaultValue = MemberID;
    adsCart1.SelectParameters["ProductID"].DefaultValue = ProductID;
    adsCart1.SelectParameters["Quantity"].DefaultValue = Quantity;

    adsCheckout.InsertParameters["ProductID"].DefaultValue = ProductID;
    adsCheckout.InsertParameters["MemberID"].DefaultValue = MemberID;
    adsCheckout.InsertParameters["Quantity"].DefaultValue = Quantity;

    adsCheckout.Insert();
```

But I do not know what to put in for the 2 ??? part so I only managed to transfer the memberID to the Checkout Table.)

Sorry if the Question is too long. Please help me to solve this problem or tell me the better way to transfer data from one table to another table. I also need help in creating simple search engine for products for my website.

Comment: try `insert into chechout select productid,memberid,quantity from cart where memberid=@` @ is any id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO [Checkout] ([ProductID], [MemberID], [Quantity]) 
SELECT [ProductID], [MemberID], [Quantity]
FROM [Cart] 
WHERE [MemberID]=?
```

Use SQL are per your first thoughts. The above statement should get the values you require. All you need to do is specify a member ID in the Where clause.

More information :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189872.aspx

Comment: Error in SELECT clause: expression near ','.
Missing FROM clause.
Unable to parse query text. This error will come out if the values are removed

Comment: Post your exact SQL statement so we can help

Comment: still unable to parse query. is it visual web developer 2008 express edition is not SQL friendly?

Comment: i didnt replace the ? with anything. now it say error in where near ; and no value given for the parameters.

Comment: Yes thanks MAN it works after i removed the ; from the sql statement. thanks alot! now i have to work in deleting the cart data after transfered to the checkout table and lastly add a search engine into my site. can tell me how to delete the cart data after transfered to checkout table?

Comment: Mark this question as answered and create a new one for the deletion. Either I or someone else will help you. Ill remove my comments above to tidy the question up. Glad it worked!!